# Convert ByteArray To String Java

Tags: java, string, arrays

I am getting byte array value(from server) as below

> byte[] byte=9D 37 7B 10 CE 77 8C 49 38 B3 C7 E2 C6 3A 22 9A ;

need to convert it to string as it is

i have tried the following code

> String item=new String(byte)

But I'm getting the value as `[B@40e5d338`

and also i tried using encoding technique

> String item=new String(byte,"UTF-8")
>
> �E��V�r��u�i��

Any Help Would be greatly Appreciated .Thank's In Advance

Comment: Perhaps you should show some code (send/receive methods from server to client)

Comment: Code and output is given above.Thanks for the comment

Comment: No, you showed one line of code. Show us your send/receive methods.

Comment: Show the line of code which is returning your the byte array please

Comment: @NareshKumar: Only output is given. Show us a short but complete example that recreates the the output you get. In cases like this, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is the best. Most of the time you'll solve the problem yourself when creating it.

Comment: `byte[] byte=9D ...` isn't a line of code. It doesn't come particularly close to compiling.

Comment: This "9D 37 7B 10 CE 77 8C 49 38 B3 C7 E2 C6 3A 22 9A"  is sample data i am getting from the server as ByteArray .

Comment: Also you can't use `byte` as array name  as its `reserved keyword in java`

Comment: In [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), the output isn't particularly readable, and Java prints it correctly in the second example. What do you expect it to be?

Comment: The problem with not giving a proper example (containing compilable code and desired output) is that we may have to make a lot of (possibly incorrect) assumptions about what you want.

Comment: "But I'm getting the value as [B@40e5d338" - that's because you're printing the byte array, not the string.

Comment: "and also i tried using encoding technique" - that string isn't [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded, so you're getting replacement characters (the question mark in a diamond). The 9D is also a control character in ISO-8859, so that's probably not the encoding either.

Comment: Bottom line: you probably aren't getting a "string" (text data) from the server. So you probably shouldn't be trying to convert the binary data that you are getting to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String constructor(s) that take byte[] as parameter create a string by converting the bytes to characters based on an encoding. If you want a string that contains

```
9D 37 7B 10 CE 77 8C 49 38 B3 C7 E2 C6 3A 22 9A
```

You'll have to write a method that does that (as far as I know there isn't one in the java library). So basically:

```
public String toHexString(byte[] arr) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(arr[0] & 0xff));
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sb.append(' ').append(Integer.toHexString(arr[i] & 0xff));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: BA 45 C8 F6 04 56 A6 72 E0 03 A8 75 E4 69 D0 EB
This is the ByteArray .When I convert using ur method. it results as      ba 45 c8 f6 4 56 a6 72 e 03 a8 75 e4 69 d0 eb. "0" at 10th and 18th position are eliminated .Other-than this Working Fine. Can You please look after it . ThankYou

Comment: replace 'Integer.toHexString(arr[i] & 0xff)' with 'String.format("%02x", arr[i] & 0xff)'